# comparing strings then scoring comparison once

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a homework problem that I have almost solved, but I am missing something. Problem,
"Simon Says" is a memory game where "Simon" outputs a sequence of 10 characters (R, G, B, Y) and the user must repeat the sequence. Create a for loop that compares the two strings starting from index 0. For each match, add one point to userScore. Upon a mismatch, exit the loop using a break statement. Assume simonPattern and userPattern are always the same length.

> Ex: The following patterns yield a userScore of 4:
>
> simonPattern: RRGBRYYBGY, userPattern:  RRGBBRYBGY

I should only count the number of matches once, the example should count matched letters only once.  Here is my code.

```
  String simonPattern;
  String userPattern;
  int userScore;
  int i;

  userScore = 0;
  simonPattern = scnr.next();
  userPattern  = scnr.next();

  /* Your solution goes here  */
   for (i=0; i < 10; ++i){

     if (simonPattern.charAt(i)==userPattern.charAt(i))
     {
        userScore+=1;
        }
     }


  System.out.println("userScore: " + userScore);

  return;
  }
}
```

The counts the matches by position, but it counts letters twice, thus I get this message.

> Testing: RRGBRYYBGY/RRGBBRYBGY
>   Output differs. See highlights below.
>
> Your output userScore: 8
>   Expected output userScore: 4

Any suggestions?

Comment: To the contrary, I see 8 characters in common between the two strings.  You should explain why you expect 4 here.

Comment: The question is looking for 4 because once the letter is matched, the user count stops. The test matches R 2 times in the same position, but it is supposed to match R once then score 1, move to G score one, move to B score one, move to Y score one, and then stop scoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not terminated loop while there is a mismatch. Use this:

```
if (simonPattern.charAt(i)==userPattern.charAt(i))
{
    userScore+=1;
}
else
    break;
```

As you are not breaking the loop, 1st 4 letters and last 4 letters are matched. So your calculation giving you 4 + 4 = 8.

Comment: Can I break the loop once a match is made and then go back in and make the next match with a break?

Comment: after breaking the loop, you can't iterate the loop again. For running the loop, you will have to call the method again. But why do you will break if there is a match? Your problem says you will break when there is a mismatch. @RBoyer

Comment: Adding else block should solve your problem. Haven't this solved your problem? @RBoyer